# Javascript load document libraries dynamically by parameter

Tags: javascript, iframe, parameter

So, I have asked several questions on this topic and each one resulted in a bit of progress. I believe I am now on the last step and I am not sure why this javascript doesn't work.

The basic goal is to grab a document library's URL based on the parameter of the current page. So for example, if I am on the project dashboard for project 1, the URL would look like this:

```
oursite.sharepoint.com/sites/subsite/projectPages/projectDashboard.aspx?ProjectCode=Proj1
```

On this page will be all of the information about the project, including a view of the most recent documents from the associated library(i.e. dl_project1 for this parameter). In order to create a recent documents view, I have an iframe with the source being the document library and a view called recent that shows recently modified items by the current user (i.e. /sites/subsite/dl_project1/forms/recent.aspx)

Now, what I am stuck on is how I retrieve the document library name. I will paste the full javascript i am using below, but the gist of what it does:

1. grab the parameter from the current url (ProjectCode=x, returns the x)
2. Using a CAML query, find the document library name that is associated with said project code. This is done through a custom list. One column is projectcode, a lookup to the project codes used for parameters. The other column is a text column with the name of the associated doclib. For example i might have: projectCode=proj1  and  documentLibrary=dl_proj1
3. Break apart the current URL, and reconstruct the correct URL for the document library
4. Display the doclib using the doclib's url in an iframe

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");

       function retrieveListItems() {
           //retrieve the document library's name
           var parameter = GetUrlKeyValue('ProjectCode'); //get the parameter name, tested and it works
           var docLibName;

           var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(); //create client context at this site collection.
           var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ProjectParameters'); //create list object by the title of the, projectParameters is the list to look through
           var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery(); //create CAMLquery to pull in list items.
           camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Title\'/>' + 
           '<Value Type=\'Computed\'>' + parameter + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>' + 
           '<RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>'); //define the query, here we pull in the field where the parameter matches. 
           this.collListitem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);//get the items from the list object based on the query defined above.

           clientContext.load(collListitem);//telling the object model to prepare to execute the following object by loading it into the client context.

           clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));  

           //break apart the url
           var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
           var firstLevelLocation = pathArray[1];
           var secondLevelLocation = pathArray[2];
           var thirdLevelLocation = pathArray[3];
           var viewUrl = '/Forms/AllItems.aspx';

           //put the docliburl back together
           var docLibUrl = window.location.protocol+ "//" + window.location.host + "/" + firstLevelLocation + "/" + secondLevelLocation + "/" + thirdLevelLocation + "/" + docLibName + viewUrl;

           //add the docliburl to the iframe's src attribute
           modIframe(docLibUrl);
       }
       function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
           var listItemInfo = '';
           var listItemEnumerator = collListitem.getEnumerator();

           while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
               var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
               listItemInfo += oListItem.get_item('i3hc');//ih3c is the internal name for the text column that contains doclib names
           }

           docLibName= listItemInfo;//set the doclibname to the pulled field

       }

       function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
           alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
       }
                   function modIframe(DocumentLibraryUrl){
           document.getElementById('doclibView').src=DocumentLibraryUrl;
       }

   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <iframe src='' height=400 width=600 id='doclibView'>
     </iframe>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

The problem that currently stands... If i put an alert in the onQuerySucceeded method, to alert the docLibName, it alerts the correct name. However, when i add in the code to display the iframe it doesn't update docLibName for some reason. It says page not found.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the `iframe` source after you retrieved the data. This should go inside the `onQuerySucceeded` event as below

```
function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListitem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += oListItem.get_item('i3hc');//ih3c is the internal name for the text column that contains doclib names
    }

    docLibName= listItemInfo;//set the doclibname to the pulled field
     //break apart the url
    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
    var firstLevelLocation = pathArray[1];
    var secondLevelLocation = pathArray[2];
    var thirdLevelLocation = pathArray[3];
    var viewUrl = '/Forms/AllItems.aspx';

    //put the docliburl back together
    var docLibUrl = window.location.protocol+ "//" + window.location.host + "/" + firstLevelLocation + "/" + secondLevelLocation + "/" + thirdLevelLocation + "/" + docLibName + viewUrl;

    //add the docliburl to the iframe's src attribute
    modIframe(docLibUrl);
}
```

Comment: You, my friend, are the very best. If only I could upvote this more. The very last struggle I have is getting rid of the header/nav bars so it is just the documents (maybe include the doclib title). Any ideas there?

Comment: You can pass the query string IsDlg=1 and that will take care of this